# unable to access POST values of input attached to DOM

Tags: jquery, laravel

I know this question has probably been asked before,but it still does not solve my problem.
I am  appending input field in a form but have been unable to access the POST data for this field. When I debug with my console, the element shows up but if I open the source code in browser it only shows one input field and wont show the appended ones.

And when I do this in my controller:

```
public function post_create_subjects()
    {
        return var_dump($_POST);
    }
```

I only get inputs for one field.

Here is my jQuery code and html.

```
<script>
//Create new subject field
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#new_subject').click(function(){
    $('table.subjects').append("<tr><td><input type='text' name='subject[]' placeholder='e.g English' class='login span3 subject' /></td><td><input type='text' name='code[]' placeholder='e.g Eng101'  class='login span2 subject' /></td></tr>");
  });
    return false;
  });
  </script>


<div id="return_data" class="red"></div>

<!-- ADD MORE SUBJECT TO CLASS -->
<table class="table subjects">
<tr>
<th>Subject Name</th>
<th>Subject Code</th> 
</tr>
<form action="{{route('create_subjects',[$Class->id])}}" method="post" class="">
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="subject[]" placeholder="e.g English" class="login span3 subject" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="code[]"      placeholder="e.g Eng101"  class="login span2 subject" /></td>
 </tr>
<button class="btn btn-google-alt" href=""><i class=" icon-ok"></i>Submit Subjects</button>
</form>
<button id="new_subject"><i class=" icon-plus-sign"></i>Add More Subjects</button>

</table>
```

Please - what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Because you are appending input fields outside the <form> tag.
Append your input tags to <form>, it will work.

Comment: He wrote `$('table.subjects').append(...`, it means he is appending contetnt to table and <form> is already closed inside table. Before "Add More Subjects" button.

Comment: i gave my form a class="subjects", and did $('form.subjects').append(.., nothing happen,it wont append anything

Comment: I don't even see how it's getting submitted? There's buttons but no submit button?

Comment: Also, unrelated, you have a button in your table that's not attached to a row/cell.

Comment: am using ajax to submit the form.never mind, all i just had to do was to wrap the from around the table.this way appended element stay in from.Thanks everyone